# Using VBA Replace Function to add to a specific part of a string excel

Tags: excel, vba

The output of a script I have is generating a string of two sentences, now separated only with a space. 
Currently, the script has joined the strings from A1 and A2 to get A3

A1 `Mary had`

A2 `a little lamb`

A3 `Mary had a little lamb`

However, I'd like to insert a carriage return to separate the two strings using the replace function.

It feels like there should be a way to have excel count the string in A1 and then add a carriage return that far into A3.

What I have so far is below, but it's currently replacing all of `Mary had` with a return. Is there something simple I'm missing?

`Range = Replace(A3, Left(A3, InStr(A3.Value, A1.Value)), vbLf)`

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is concatenate the values of cells A1 and A2, adding a new line between them,  and set the result to cell A3.
You can do it fairly easy as such :

`A3.Value = A1.Value & vbNewLine & A2.Value`

Answer (score 1):

This is based off the guess that A1 and A2 are already designated as strings.  I dont  think you need a `replace` function unless its required for something else in your project.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim A1 As String, A2 As String, A3 As String

    A1 = "Mary had"
    A2 = "a little lamb"

    A3 = A1 & vbCrLf & A2

    Debug.Print A3

End Sub
```